# Does AWS managed Active Directory supports AD FS SAML for AWS Cognito?

Tags: saml-2.0, amazon-cognito, adfs, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to setup cognito user pool from AWS Microsoft AD. However I'm not sure where can I get the metadata document from. I'm using AWS managed active directory solution

Answer (score 0):

AWS Microsoft AD creates AD in the AWS cloud.

ADFS (which does have SAML metadata) sits as a layer on top of AD so you can't get SAML metadata at the AD level.

Refer: [SAML Identity provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/saml-identity-provider.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to do add adfs using ec2 instances. 
 However it complained that my user is  without domain admin rights. As I uderstood I don't have them with aws managed ad, right? does it mean, I have to create my own AD on a ec2 instance?